# Optional variables in Azure Function triggered by BLOB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, blob, azure-blob-storage

When configuring a blob trigger for an Azure function, it is possible to use pattern matching on the blob name to map portions of the name, to variables in the function. For example:

```
[FunctionName("BlobTriggered")]        
public static void BlobTriggered(
    [BlobTrigger("myContainer/{name}.{extension}")] Stream myBlob,
    string name,
    string extension,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    ...
}
```

But what if I wanted one of the variables to be optional? For the given example, what if I wanted the extension to be optional? Thus, I would need to make the `.`, and the extension itself, to be optional. Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried setting a default value on the extension? `string name, string extension = "",`

Comment: What do you mean optional? You want to filter the extension?

Comment: @ffffff01 that wouldn't work because of the `.`, right?

@GeorgeChen I want files to be uploaded to match the expression, regardless of having, or not, an extension. So I could process a file named 123, as well as 123.png.

Comment: @ffffff01 I have just tried and if I would have the `.{extension}` in the string used for pattern matching, the function would never be triggered whenever files without extension would be added to BLOB storage

Comment: I will make myself a function later today and test.

Comment: @ccoutinho Why just don't remove the pattern hand extract the extension yourself?
`BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "teststorage_STORAGE")`

Comment: That's how I am solving it right now, I just though I could make that better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the pattern and handle the filename and extension yourself like this.

```
    public static void Run([BlobTrigger("test/{name}", Connection = "teststorage_STORAGE")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Name: {Path.GetFileName(name)}");
        log.LogInformation($"Extension: {Path.GetExtension(name)}");
    }
```

Log entries below where the first upload is with extension and the last without.

[image]